# Allow final preview without a title for iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, markdown-preview

Currently for final post preview in iOS app you need to specify a title (before tapping on yellow area surrounded with free hand red circle):

> [image: preview]

Sometimes l want to check how the post body will be looked, and I don't plan to publish it now. So I don't see any reason why title is necessary for preview, especially when tags (obligatory components of the question) could be omitted (you don't need to specify tags at all).

I think that presence of title is redundant for preview purposes only. It's annoying when I need type title there. Moreover web version of Stack Exchange doesn't require title existence for preview. So why the app is requesting it?

Could it please be removed?